# HashMap initialization with values in parenthesis

Tags: java, hashmap

When I saw a Java program, some of it is about initialization of HashMap, and it seems to be very strange.

Suppose I have a HashMap, let's call it "map1", and then `HashMap<> map2=new HashMap<>(map1)`. 
What does this line means?

I omit something in the `<>` which is unimportant.

I really appreciate for that!

Comment: Please post the full original code.  This looks like nothing more than creating a map with a generic type from another map.

Comment: Look at the constructors of HahMap, you can initialise one with another.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap%28java.util.Map%29):

> `public HashMap(Map<? extends K,? extends V> m)`
>
> Constructs a new `HashMap` with the same mappings as the specified `Map`. The `HashMap` is created with default load factor (0.75) and an initial capacity sufficient to hold the mappings in the specified `Map`.